# no module named tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow, anaconda

I installed **tensorflow CPU** version in **windows** as mentined on their official page.

It got installed successfully but giving error while I import the library.

Output for **pip freeze** also shows it's present:

```
spyder==3.1.2
SQLAlchemy==1.1.5
statsmodels==0.6.1
sympy==1.0
tables==3.2.2
tensorflow==1.0.1
toolz==0.8.2
tornado==4.4.2
traitlets==4.3.1
```

**Using anaconda.**

Comment: I had problems when I update pip... I solve the problem unistalling python and installing in my user folder (C://Users/YourUser)..

Comment: I am using anaconda. So I tried to create a new environment and then install tensorflow . But not working. This is weird. Few hours ago it was working just fine

Comment: Im sorry I cant help you :(

Answer (score 0):

If you have python 2.X installed along with a Python 3.X do pip(version) example; pip3 instead of pip. I had a similar problem so i had a look around and someone said do pip3.6.1 but it spewed out an error so a few trys later pip3 worked. If not idk whats happening

Comment: 'pip3' is not recognized as an internal or external command. Getting in Python 3.x env .

Comment: What os are you on?

Comment: I am on windows os

Comment: Strange let me look

Comment: Sorry im stumped i'll get back to you once i have found why pip3 wont work. It may be due to the environment